# rbind in R gives a weird rowname

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframes `tt1`

```
> tt1[2,]
        date  close emp pred
2 1982-03-24 112.97  -1    1
```

and dataframe `tt2`

```
> tt2[2,]
        date  close emp pred
2 1982-03-25 113.21   1    1
```

when I try to use `rbind()` I get weird row name for the 2nd row.

```
> rbind(tt1[2,],tt2[2,])
         date  close emp pred
2  1982-03-24 112.97  -1    1
21 1982-03-25 113.21   1    1
```

any clue has to how to get rid of that have it as 1, 2

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
rownames(mydataframe) <- NULL
```

See the documentation (type `?rownames` on the prompt) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have duplicate rownames in a data frame or matrix. `rbind()` checks the rownames on the object it creates and adjusts duplicate rownames to make them unique.

You can easily reset the row names, here is a simple example:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 1:3)
dat2 <- data.frame(A = 4:6, B = 4:6)

out <- rbind(dat1[2,], dat2[2,])
rownames(out) <- NULL
```

Giving

```
> out
  A B
1 2 2
2 5 5
```