# R duplicated rownames with original number +1

Tags: r, dataframe

The issue is:
I'm running simulation and prediction on some data set, basically the problem is when doing cross validation of 10k fold, it randomly draw 10 % of my original data out, but when putting the results into a whole data frame, I'll get like an additional 1 or 2 or .. when merging them.

My example is bad, so I'm borrowing it from another post: [rbind in R gives a weird rowname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524140/rbind-in-r-gives-a-weird-rowname)

```
 > tt1[2,]
         date  close emp pred
 2 1982-03-24 112.97  -1    1

 > tt2[2,]
         date  close emp pred
 2 1982-03-25 113.21   1    1
```

Problem:

```
 > rbind(tt1[2,],tt2[2,])
          date  close emp pred
 2  1982-03-24 112.97  -1    1
 21 1982-03-25 113.21   1    1
```

What I want:

```
 > rbind(tt1[2,],tt2[2,])
          date  close emp pred
 2  1982-03-24 112.97  -1    1
 2  1982-03-25 113.21   1    1
```

Any helps would be great, thank you all.

Best,
K

Comment: The question has been changed... Matthew's answer works.

Comment: Thanks to you as well @sashkello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is using the originally posted data:

```
data_1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, GPA = c(3, 3.5, 4)), .Names = c("ID", 
"GPA"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
data_2 <- structure(list(ID = 3:5, GPA = c(3.1, 3.2, 3.3)), .Names = c("ID", 
"GPA"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("3", "4", "5"))
```

(Ignore the fact that the `ID` column agrees with the rowname.)

You can capture the original row names (to apply them later, if desired):

```
rbind(cbind(rn=rownames(data_1), data_1), cbind(rn=rownames(data_2), data_2))
##    rn ID GPA
## 1   1  1 3.0
## 2   2  2 3.5
## 3   3  3 4.0
## 31  3  3 3.1
## 4   4  4 3.2
## 5   5  5 3.3
```

This can be parameterized in a few ways.  Here is one:

```
d <- list(data_1, data_2)
do.call(rbind, lapply(d, function(x) cbind(rn=rownames(x), x)))
##    rn ID GPA
## 1   1  1 3.0
## 2   2  2 3.5
## 3   3  3 4.0
## 31  3  3 3.1
## 4   4  4 3.2
## 5   5  5 3.3
```